# ¿Cómo podría un input tomar la info que tiene un select por default? sin seleccionar

Tags: javascript, jquery

En el código de muestra esta seleccionado en el combo (Select) "valor uno", pero este no muestra nada en el input.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta seleccionar otra opción ejemplo:
seleccionando primero "valor dos" y después "valor uno".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De qué manera podría tomar el valor por default?

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function() { //detectamos el evento change
    var value = $(this).val(); //sacamos el valor del select
    $('#myInput').val(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Valor uno</option>
  <option value="2">Valor dos</option>
  <option value="3">Valor tres</option>
</select>

<input id="myInput">
```

Comment: Veo que usas `jQuey` y en el código no muestras nada de `PHP`, así que me tomé la libertad de modificar las etiquetas para no confundir.

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas te ha servido, te animo a aceptarla con el check del lado izquierdo para que sirva de referencia a futuros visitantes. En caso contrario, déjanos un comentario para saber si podemos ayudarte de otra manera.

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente debes ejecutar la función en dos momentos, al cargar la página y en el evento `onchange`.

Dejo el código comentado por si hay dudas.

```js
//Hacer que se ejecute la función al cargar la pagina
$(document).ready(function() {
  asignarValor();
});

//Declarar la función
function asignarValor() {
  //Capturar el valor del select
  let valorSeleccionado = $('#mySelect').val();
  //Pasarlo al input
  $('#myInput').val(valorSeleccionado);
};

//Y en el evento onchange se ejecuta nuevamente la función
$(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function() {
  asignarValor();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Valor uno</option>
  <option value="2">Valor dos</option>
  <option value="3">Valor tres</option>
</select>

<input id="myInput">
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con esto,

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1" selected>Valor uno</option>
  <option value="2">Valor dos</option>
  <option value="3">Valor tres</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias por contribuir con la comunidad. Hay una serie de lineamientos para dar respuestas de calidad. Consulta [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Trata de mejorarla para que reciba mejor puntuación.